# Rails 3 - Get Multiple Counts from same child table with different Where Clauses

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a relationship between Job Shifts and People who have indicated whether they want to apply of the jobs (Yes, No or Maybe).

I Want to list a Job Shift and the Count of people that have indicated Yes, No or Maybe.

My Current Query Does not work and I not sure why, I am new to Rails so I would also like to know if there is a more Railish way of doing this.

[image]

```
def report_shift_detail
    @headers = ["id", "staffroom_id", "title", "Yes", "No", "Maybe"]
    @fields = [:id, :staffroom_id, :title, :count_yes, :count_no, :count_maybe]

    @sql = Shift.scoped
      .select("shifts.id, shifts.staffroom_id, shifts.title, count(application_yes.id) as count_yes, count(application_no.id) as count_no, count(application_maybe.id) as count_maybe")
      .joins("INNER JOIN shift_applications as application_yes ON application_yes.shift_id = shifts.id")
      .where("application_yes.sort = 'yes'")
      .joins("INNER JOIN shift_applications as application_no ON application_no.shift_id = shifts.id")
      .where("application_no.sort = 'no'")
      .joins("INNER JOIN shift_applications as application_maybe ON application_maybe.shift_id = shifts.id")
      .where("application_maybe.sort = 'maybe'")
      .group("shifts.id")
end
```

Comment: I don't know exactly what are ur model names  but u can try something like this  `@values = People.joins(:shift).select(:id, :staffroom, :title, :application_maybe, :application_yes, :application_no).uniq.to_a`

Answer (score 2):

I'm posting partial answer as it may be useful. I do not have a nice RUBY answer as I'm not proficient enough to construct this as RUBY but I got the query working by restructing the select statement, I was writing it incorrectly from the start.

Here is the working SQL

```
SELECT shifts.id, shifts.staffroom_id, shifts.title, 
    (select count(*) from shift_applications where shift_applications.shift_id = shifts.id AND (shift_applications.sort = 'yes')) as count_yes,
    (select count(*) from shift_applications where shift_applications.shift_id = shifts.id AND (shift_applications.sort = 'no')) as count_no,
    (select count(*) from shift_applications where shift_applications.shift_id = shifts.id AND (shift_applications.sort = 'maybe')) as count_maybe
FROM "shifts" 
WHERE "shifts"."deleted" = 'f' 
GROUP BY shifts.id
```

Here is how I implemented it in Ruby

```
count_yes = "(select count(*) from shift_applications where shift_applications.shift_id = shifts.id AND (shift_applications.sort = 'yes')) as count_yes"
count_no = "(select count(*) from shift_applications where shift_applications.shift_id = shifts.id AND (shift_applications.sort = 'no')) as count_no"
count_maybe = "(select count(*) from shift_applications where shift_applications.shift_id = shifts.id AND (shift_applications.sort = 'maybe')) as count_maybe"

@sql = Shift.scoped
  .select("shifts.id, shifts.staffroom_id, shifts.title, #{count_yes}, #{count_no}, #{count_maybe}")
  .group("shifts.id")
```

Hopefully someone can see a cleaner way to do this

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a wild guess here, please post more info like your table columns and names. I'm assuming that you have 2 models named `Shift` and `ShiftApplication`, I'd probably do something like this:

In your controller:

```
def report_shift_detail
  @shifts = Shift.all
end
```

In your report_shift_detail.html.erb, I will have something like this

```
<% @shifts.each do |shift| %>
<tr>
  <td> <%= shift.shift_applications.where(sort: 'yes').count %></td>
  <td> <%= shift.shift_applications.where(sort: 'no').count %></td>
  <td> <%= shift.shift_applications.where(sort: 'maybe').count %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

Of course if it where me, I'm going to define a scope in my model instead of doing the `where` in the views. This is the only thing I can manage based on your example.

Comment: Hi Finks, thanks for this reply, unfortunately we currently have code similar to this and even with .includes it just takes way to long to process the data and times out on Heroku. I have an updated SQL which now works and I'll post it for others